# How to make WPF Window behave like a "Native Window"

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to add native window functionality to my WPF Window which has NoResize ResizeMode and None WindowStyle

For example when a window is dragged to the top of the screen, it should show the Windows expand animation and then expand if it is dropped there, or when the window is dragged to either sides of the screen it should automatically resize to occupy half of the screen.

I think it would not be that bad to manually implement those functionalities, but I was wondering if there is a "best" way to do that.

Edit:
The reason I am doing this is because I want to change the title bar style. I cannot use `ResizeMode=CanResize` because I get a white line over the window. The white line can be fixed with `AllowTransparency=True`, but I use a `HwndHost` to interact with a 3rd party library, and `AllowTransparency=True` breaks HwndHosts.

Comment: Why do it yourself, when Windows can do the work for you?

Comment: How exactly do you want to change the title?

Comment: Because "just" changing title would likely be your simplest approach, remove windowstyle none and start from there.

Comment: @ClausH I edited the post to explain my dilemma

Comment: @Andy I have already changed the title like that is fine. I added drag functionality to the window. Now if you drag a window to the top of the screen it maximizes. Mine doesn't.